# the invertibility of (I-B)

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $X$ be  a banach space and $M$ be a nonempty weakly compact convex subset of $X$ , I have $G$ a multivalued map and $B\in L(X)$ , my question  is when i define the map 
$(I-B)^{-1}G(x)$ , i should show that (I-B) is invertible or no ? because $G(x)$ is a set ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, since $(I-B)^{-1}G(x)=\{z \in X:(I-B)z \in G(x)\}$.